# How to hint optimizer that function have distributive property?

Tags: c++

I length-validating function that should be called before every read, that throws exception. Is there any way to tell compiler that it may squash `f(a), f(b)` into `f(a+b)`, but it should be before reads from memory.

Example:

```
struct PacketReader {
void *data;
size_t size, offset;
inline void validate(size_t len) const {
    if(offset+len > size)
        throw std::length_error("");
}
inline uint8_t readByte() {
    validate(1);
    return ((uint8_t*)data)[offset++];
}
}
/// Some code later
{
    PacketReader rd = getPacket();
    uint8_t a=rd.readByte(), b=rd.readByte();
}
```

Expected (pseudo)code after optimization:

```
{
    PacketReader rd = getPacket();
    validate(2);
    uint8_t a=((uint8_t*)rd.data)[rd.offset++],
            b=((uint8_t*)rd.data)[rd.offset++];
}
```

Comment: You could make your function return multiple values via `std::tie` or `std::array` and then use a [structured binding declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding).

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: It might rearrange it with the "as-if" rule. But it would probably require that compiler see all code. As `validate` might throw, it needs that all interleaving code would have no side effect to be allowed to reorder code.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to tell to compiler that 2 expression are equivalent (especially where there are not in general case).

Comment: The two fragments shown are not equivalent. You say `validate` throws if the length is insufficient. Then, if there's enough to read one byte but not two, the first fragment increments `offset` once before throwing, while the second leaves it unchanged. An optimizer generally cannot modify the program in a way that alters its observable behavior.

Comment: Igor, yes I thought about that and I have no idea how to tell compiler that it doesn't matters where exception is thrown as long as it was thrown before read. I also can call validate explicitly and hope future calls will be optimized-out, but that is not what I'm asking.

Comment: "that is not what I'm asking" In a way it is. You have two non-equivalent pieces of code and want to tell the compiler to replace one with the other. The simplest way to "say" this is to make them equivalent. Either call validate(2) first or have an RAII offset rollback. Once you have equivalent code, you can play with the spelling to trigger the optimization on your chosen compiler version and arch. The compiler will rarely transform code to observably different code.